# How to save PDF form(user fills and submit) data into Database using .NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there any way to submit PDF form data on all browsers like chrome, Firefox,Safari etc. over server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `iTextSharp`

Answer (score -1):

Yep.

1) Create a button on the PDF form
2) Under Actions, select trigger "Mouse Up" and select action "Submit a form"
3) In the next dialog, enter the URL that you want the data to go to.
4) Select "HTML"

Your data will be sent as HTTP POST data with "FieldName=value"

Good luck!